# I have some problem about edit DataTable by DTedit package in shiny r

Tags: r, shinydashboard

`my.callback.update`, `my.callback.insert`, `my.callback.delete` functions don't work and the table after editing don't save.

I tried making this in shiny r

app.R

```
library(shiny)

library(shinydashboard)

library(DTedit)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "EditDatatable"),

  dashboardSidebar(

    sidebarMenu(

      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))

      )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",

       fluidPage(

         fluidRow(

           uiOutput('mycontacts') 

         )

       )

      )

    )     

  )

)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  load("D:\\editDatatable/mydata.RData")

 my.insert.callback <- function(data, row) {
    mydata <- rbind(data, mydata)
    return(mydata)
  }

  my.update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row) {
    mydata[row,] <- data[1,]
    return(mydata)
  }

  my.delete.callback <- function(data, row) {
    mydata[row,] <- NULL
    return(mydata)
  }

  # save(mydata, file = "D:\\editDatatable/mydata.RData")

  output$mycontacts <- renderUI(

    DTedit::dtedit(input, output, 

                  name = 'mycontacts',

                  thedata = mydata,

                  edit.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR', 'notes'),

                  edit.label.cols = c('Name', 'Email Address', 'Are they an R user?', 'Additional notes'),

                  input.types = c(notes='textAreaInput'),

                  view.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR', 'notes'),

                  my.callback.update = my.update.callback,

                  my.callback.insert = my.insert.callback,

                  my.callback.delete = my.delete.callback)

)}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the result I must take:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/editable-datatables-for-shiny-applications/

Help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Please provide a reproducing example with data or dummy data. 2. Looks like you are not defining your callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the documentation currently (21st June 2020) shown [on the README of `jbryer/DTedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit) is misleading about the contents of `data`/`olddata`/`row`, as is mentioned in some of the comments on [JBryer's blog page about `DTedit`](https://bryer.org/post/2018-22-26-dtedit/).

Here is revised documentation as described on [my current modified version of `DTedit`](https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit), describing what `data`/`olddata`/`row` *actually* contain.

```r
my.insert.callback <- function(data, row) {
  # 'data' contains the dataframe *after* the row has been inserted/added
  # 'row' is the row number where data has been inserted
  mydata <<- rbind(mydata, data[row,])
  # in this case, 'mydata' should just be the same as 'data'
  return(mydata)
}

my.update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row) {
  # 'data' contains the dataframe *after* the row has been updated
  # 'row' is the row number where data has been updated
  # 'olddata' is the previous version of the data
  mydata[row,] <<- data[row,]
  # in this case, 'mydata' should just be the same as 'data'
  return(mydata)
}

my.delete.callback <- function(data, row) {
  # 'data' contains the dataframe *before* the row has been deleted
  # 'row' is the row number where data is to be deleted
  mydata <<- mydata[-row,]
  # in this case, 'mydata' should just be the same as data[-c(row),]
  return(mydata)
}
```

An example of the correct use of callback functions is shown in the [`dtedit_demo` of `jbryer/DTedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit/blob/master/inst/shiny_demo/app.R).

Even more examples are shown in [my vignette of `DTedit` on RPubs](https://rpubs.com/DavidFong/DTedit), but quite a few of those examples are specific to modifications I made to `DTedit`.